# Typescript - Property 'scrollY' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: typescript

I got this method:

```
class Foo {
    private getDistanceFromTop (el: HTMLElement): number {
        return el.scrollY || el.scrollTop;
    }
}
```

The `el` argument is dynamic and can be an `HTMLElement` or an `window` object. I tried to convert it to `Window` type using `as`, but another compilation error appears: `Type 'HTMLElement' cannot be converted to type 'Window'`.  So how do I modify this code in order to make it pass TS validation and without using the `:any` type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTMLElement and Window are two different types so you could do something like this:

```js
class Foo {
  private getDistanceFromTop(el: HTMLElement | Window) {
    if (el instanceof Window) {
      return el.scrollY;
    }
    return el.scrollTop;
  }
}
```