# How to use .should with the "closeTo" assertion in Cypress?

Tags: testing, e2e-testing, cypress

In this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50004068/7489488), the following code snippet was posted.

```js
cy.window().then(($window) => {
  expect($window.scrollY).to.be.closeTo(400, 100);
});
```

However, I would like to use the "should" syntax as shown below.

```js
// This code works
cy.window().its('scrollY').should('equal', 400);
```

**How can I use "should" and "closeTo" together in Cypress (the following does not work)?**

```js
// This code doesn't work
cy.window().its('scrollY').should('closeTo', 400, 100);
```

The [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Effect-on-default-DOM-assertions) doesn't seem to show an example for the above case.

Answer (score 1):

Upon closer inspection of the documentation, I believe the following is what I'm after.

```js
cy.window().its('scrollY').should(($scrollY) => {
    expect($scrollY).to.be.closeTo(400, 100);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

`getScrollContainer().invoke('scrollTop').should('be.closeTo', 10, 100)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).